# Unicorn Sync configuration for Sitecore SXA site

Tags: sxa, unicorn, serialization

I need to achieve below in one config file but getting some conflict error.

could you please help on this. I want to avoid creating multiple files for this purpose only by setting up dependency.

```
<include name="Content.xxx" database="master" path="/sitecore/content/xxx">
                    <exclude children="true" />
                </include>
                <include name="Content.xxx.yyy" database="master" path="/sitecore/content/xxx/yyy">
                    <exclude children="true" />
                </include>
                <include name="Content.xxx.Corporate" database="master" path="/sitecore/content/xxx/yyy/Corporate">
                    <exclude children="true" />
                </include>
```

Comment: What is the config error?

Comment: And why are you putting the children of a config into another config? Why not just keep them in one include path?

Comment: if I need "/sitecore/content/xxx/yyy/Corporate" means I need to have parrent node "/sitecore/content/xxx/yyy". xxx is tenant folder, yyy is tenant name and Corporate is site name. these all 3 nodes(xxx, yyy and Corporate) I need excluding children.

Comment: Ahh ok. Thank you. What is the error?

Comment: The trees Content.xxx and Content.xxx.yyy both contained the global path /sitecore/content/xxx/Presence - overlapping trees are not allowed.

Comment: Can you please try breaking each up into its own configuration. https://gist.github.com/dnstommy/a6a1c0a56685da668e62c57befdb7e6e

Answer (score 3):

You can't do that in a single file. Once you exclude children of root item you cannot, later on, include it back.

You separate files for this, e.g.:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
    <sitecore>
        <unicorn>
            <configurations>
                <configuration name="Content.xxx.yyy" description="Content.xxx.yyy" dependencies="...">
                    <targetDataStore physicalRootPath="..." type="Rainbow.Storage.SerializationFileSystemDataStore, Rainbow" useDataCache="false" singleInstance="true" />
                    <predicate type="Unicorn.Predicates.SerializationPresetPredicate, Unicorn" singleInstance="true">
                        <include name="YYY" database="master" path="/sitecore/content/xxx/yyy" />
                    </predicate>
                </configuration>
            </configurations>
        </unicorn>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

and the second one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
    <sitecore>
        <unicorn>
            <configurations>
                <configuration name="Content.xxx.Corporate" description="Content.xxx.Corporate" dependencies="...">
                    <targetDataStore physicalRootPath="..." type="Rainbow.Storage.SerializationFileSystemDataStore, Rainbow" useDataCache="false" singleInstance="true" />
                    <predicate type="Unicorn.Predicates.SerializationPresetPredicate, Unicorn" singleInstance="true">
                        <include name="Corporate" database="master" path="/sitecore/content/xxx/yyy/Corporate" />
                    </predicate>
                </configuration>
            </configurations>
        </unicorn>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Remember about setting up proper dependencies, so that you won't end up de-serializing child items when root item isn't there.